# How do I merge two or more single arrays into one multidimensional array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to merge two or more single arrays into one multidimensional array for example if I have the arrays

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array(6,7,8,9,10);
```

I want the final array to be a multidimensional array with both or more previous arrays in it

```
$arr3= array
  (
  array(1,2,3,4,5),
  array(6,7,8,9,10)
  );
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please remember to accept it. If not, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Just build a new array:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array(6,7,8,9,10);
$arr3 = array($arr1, $arr2);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/g6jrLt)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it.

```
$arr3[0] = $arr1;
$arr3[1] = $arr2;
```